# Change ToolStrip button positions dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Which property of `ToolStripButton`  is responsible for their position order on a `ToolStrip`?
I need that property so that I can dynamically change positions of `ToolStripButtons` on a `ToolStrip`.

Comment: +1. Good question. Don't know why people downvoted this.

Comment: Maybe they think this question doesn't deserve to be answered :(

Comment: Thanks for input, i did the same now

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a property for this. The buttons are contained in a `ToolStripItemCollection` which holds the general `ToolStripItem` instances. You can behave with it like a C# collection. Like other collections, you can clear it, add or insert items at any arbitrary position, etc. Like:

```
toolStrip1.Items.Clear();

toolStrip1.Items.Add(toolStripButton3);
toolStrip1.Items.Add(toolStripButton2);
toolStrip1.Items.Add(toolStripButton1);

toolStrip1.Items.Insert(toolStripButton4, 2);
```

To convert the `ToolStripItemCollection` to a C# collection with more capabilities (like Sort and Reverse) convert it to an ArrayList:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList list = new System.Collections.ArrayList(toolStrip1.Items);
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102205/how-to-sort-items-in-toolstripitemcollection) might be interesting to you too.

Comment: Thanks, I think using this I can change button positions dynamically, if am successful will post answer here

Comment: Don't understand why is my question closed. What I need is to dynamically change positions of buttons on toolstrip. I don't think this question is vague. I need this in my project.

Comment: Its closed because some people have nothing better to do than to carry on like childish bullies. The question makes perfect sense to me.